# Search all sheets except the current for a value and return true/false

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a column of values in Sheet1. I'm trying to search every other sheet in my file to see if that value is in there and get a boolean response.

The code below only searches the sheet that it appears on.

```
function searchForNumber(value) {
  return !!SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .createTextFinder(String(value))
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findNext()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function searchOthers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const col = 1;
  const sr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,col,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  const n = sh.getName();
  const oshts = ss.getSheets().filter(s => s.getName() != n).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(oshts.map(s => s.getName())))
  let o = [];
  oshts.forEach((sh, i) => {
    vs.forEach((t,j) => {
      let f = sh.createTextFinder(t).findAll();
      if(f.length > 0) {
        o.push({text: t, sheet: sh.getName(), status: true})
      } else {
        o.push({text: t, sheet: sh.getName(), status: false})
      }
    })
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
}
```

References:

- [ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: This is giving me 'Exception: Argument cannot be null: findText (line 19).'

Comment: You must have a blank row in your data it should work now.

Comment: Maybe your sr is wrong; sr is the starting row of the search string data

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wildly wrong, this seems to just return

'Error
Exceeded maximum execution time (line 0).'

Comment: It worked in my example so I cannot reproduce your results.